# How proceed to create one entry comment in db with belong_to post and membre

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have one model :comment with two belong_to one :post and others :membre

i want to do def create

with twoo var `@post_id` and `@membre_id`

how proceed for doing on one time with the twoo belong_to ?

how place var ?

Thanks for your help

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def comment_params
  params.fetch(:comment, {})
end
```

Comment: Where do `post_id` and `member_id` come from? Is the current user the member? Where will that form live, on a show post page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you've provided, try (and I'll assume membre_id is member_id):

```
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

@comment.member_id = @member_id
@comment.post_id = @post_id

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
  etc...
end
```

There are far nicer ways to do it though. If you have an @member and @post variable you can do:

```
@comment.member = @member
@comment.post = @post
```

But the nicest is to include the paramaters in the first place. Where the user is creating a comment, add in two hidden fields into the form, member_id and post_id. This way you won't need to manually assign the ID's yourself.